# Actualizar datos en un BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

Tengo un problema en Android Studio. Primero dejo el BaseAdapter:

```
public class AdaptadorGaleriaProductos extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Producto> productosArray = new ArrayList<Producto>();
Context context;
int background;
private AdaptadorBaseDeDatos adapDB;

public AdaptadorGaleriaProductos(Context context, String idCategoria)
{
    super();
    this.context = context;
    //establecemos un marco para las imágenes (estilo por defecto proporcionado)
    //por android y definido en /values/attr.xml
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    background = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
    typedArray.recycle();

    crearAdaptadorDB();
    Cursor productos;
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean conCero = sp.getBoolean("productosCero", false);

    if (conCero) {
        productos = adapDB.obtenerProductosPorCategoriaConCero(idCategoria);
    } else {
        productos = adapDB.obtenerProductosPorCategoria(idCategoria);
    }

    while (productos.moveToNext()) {
        String id = productos.getString(0);
        String nombre = productos.getString(1);
        String codigo = productos.getString(2);
        int cantidad = productos.getInt(3);
        double precioMinorista = productos.getDouble(4);
        double precioMayorista = productos.getDouble(5);
        String foto = productos.getString(6);
        String descripcion = productos.getString(7);
        Producto prod = new Producto(id, nombre, codigo, cantidad, precioMinorista, precioMayorista, foto, descripcion);
        productosArray.add(prod);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return productosArray.size();
}

@Override
public Producto getItem(int position)
{
    return productosArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return getItem(position).getCodigoHash();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imagen = new ImageView(context);

    final Producto item = getItem(position);
    try {
        Glide.with(imagen.getContext())
                .load(item.getIdImagen())
                .into(imagen);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }

    //se aplica el estilo
    imagen.setBackgroundResource(background);

    return imagen;
}
```

Y el Activity:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_galeria_productos);
    TypedArray typedArray = this.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    background = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
    typedArray.recycle();
    String idCategoria = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM_ID);
    adapGaleriaProductos = new AdaptadorGaleriaProductos(this, idCategoria);
    imagenSeleccionada = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.seleccionada);

    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(adapGaleriaProductos);

}

public void eliminarProducto(final AdaptadorGaleriaProductos adap) {
    crearAdaptadorDB();
    this.adapDB.eliminarProducto(adap.getItem(this.savePosition).getId());
    adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Cuando elimino un producto, la actividad no refleja el cambio instantaneamente. Tengo que salir y volver a entrar para ver los cambios. Como ven, he intentando con notifyDataSetChanged(), pero no funciona.

Gracias!

Comment: puedes agregar por favor eliminarProducto()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En la experiencia que tengo, `BaseAdapter` actualiza la lista si dicha lista utiliza métodos tales como:

- `add()`
- `insert()`
- `remove()`
- `clear()`

Asegurate de que en el método eliminarProducto() estas utilizando correctamente uno de los métodos listados en la lista `productosArray` que esta manejando el `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: Antes que nada gracias por la respuesta. Tengo entendido que cuando se crea el BaseAdapter, la manipulacion de los elementos se hace mediante este objeto y no directamente desde la lista. Ademas, en caso de manipular la lista, no solucionaria el problema en cuestion, ya que los cambios si se registran, pero el problema es que no me los muestra al instante, sino que tengo que cerrar y abrir nuevamente el activity.

Comment: Los elementos que contiene el BaseAdapter se basa en la lista que le pases. Si modificas tu lista con unos de los métodos listados en mi respuesta y notificas al adaptador con un notifyDataSetChanged() se actualizarán las vistas de tu adaptador. Debes hacer gallery.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Me di cuenta que el problema es que yo a la lista la creo en el adaptador, en vez de pasarsela como parametro desde el activity. Voy a hacer esta modificacion y te cuento. Gracias!